# Trying to recover encrypted partition, getting very confused

Tags: linux, encryption, data-recovery, luks, lvm2

I have a LUKS/cryptsetup encrypted disk from a friend's Debian machine which would not boot. I'm trying to mount it on another Debian machine, using a USB enclosure, to recover the data or get some clue as to the problem. I am an experienced Linux command-line user but a total n00b with LUKS and LVM.

Auto-mount does not work (it accepts the passphrase but then says something about an unusable file system, and does not mount).

So I went through this process of trying to mount it from the command line.

```
root@somepc:/dev/mapper# fdisk -l | grep sdb
Disk /dev/sdb: 149.1 GiB, 160041885696 bytes, 312581808 sectors
/dev/sdb1          2048    999423    997376   487M 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2       1001470 312580095 311578626 148.6G  5 Extended
/dev/sdb5       1001472 312580095 311578624 148.6G 83 Linux


root@somepc:~# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb5 foo
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdb5:     [Passphrase accepted]
root@somepc:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-mate-vg21
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  9
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               148.57 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              38033
  Alloc PE / Size       38027 / 148.54 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       6 / 24.00 MiB
  VG UUID               y7TB6e-b6hT-0Fpr-wXAY-6DwW-1Vyw-2bolpJ

  --- Volume group ---
  [ details of system disk ]
```

At this point I realised that my friend had made an attempt to recover it using an Ubuntu Mate machine. The following suggests he must have modified the partitions ... judging by the "LV Creation host, time" - He says he looked at it in GParted and GParted may have done something with it.

We are the blind leading the blind...

```
root@somepc:~# lvdisplay /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg21
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg21/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                ubuntu-mate-vg21
  LV UUID                wOnyHp-WXox-QatY-mQEy-Esuz-ADcP-TzVEFh
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-mate, 2017-04-08 06:50:00 +0300
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                140.87 GiB
  Current LE             36062
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg21/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                ubuntu-mate-vg21
  LV UUID                WapYkq-O3AP-r0x9-3bBW-KcWD-yCNC-mw8Gq2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-mate, 2017-04-08 06:50:01 +0300
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                7.68 GiB
  Current LE             1965
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
```

Anyway, onwards.

```
root@somepc:~# vgchange -ay ubuntu-mate-vg21
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-mate-vg21" now active
root@somepc:~# mount /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg21/root /mnt/test
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg21-root,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error

   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail or so.
```

So I googled "bad superblock" and did

```
root@somepc:~# fsck /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg21/root
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/ubuntu--mate--vg21-root

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

root@somepc:~# mke2fs -n /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg21/root
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
Creating filesystem with 36927488 4k blocks and 9232384 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 484f5abf-3fee-42a7-af1c-22f9bdde8976
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872
```

Then I tried `e2fsck -b <BLOCKNUMBER> /dev/ubuntu-mate-vg21/root` with each block number, and got the same error as above, every time.

Afterwards I read that you do not need to, and should not, run fsck on a logical volume, or something, so I hope I have not made the situation worse.

I feel there must be something more I can do before just giving up on this disk, but I'm having real trouble finding out. Perhaps I just need pointing towards some documentation.

Thanks

Comment: You ran `mke2fs`which seemed to be successful. As such you created a new FS and in doubt overwrote anything that was in it's place. Likely he did click something beforehand. What OS was the original machine running before any recovery took place?